# UITextField 'Cut' does not fill pasteboard

Tags: ios, uitextfield, copy-paste

I have a `UITextField` with no custom copy-paste-... code at all. When I Cut and then Paste it back, I see some previous pasteboard content appear.

When I Cut from the text field and then Paste in let's say iOS Notes, I also see the previous pasteboard content.

When I Cut text from Notes and Paste it back, I see the Cut text. This is the expected behaviour, so something weird seems to be going on in my app.

How can I make sure that Cut fills the pasteboard?

When I Copy and then Paste, all works as expected.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html) clearly confirms that Cut should place the selected data on the pasteboard.

Comment: What do you want to cut? Simple Unicode text? Or, for example, emojis?

Comment: Simple text, I tested with just A-Za-z for example.

Comment: @meaning-matters I know it's been a couple years but did you ever figure out this one? I'm seeing it too :/

Comment: @AdamCampbell It's only a year plus a few months ago :-) I did not find a solution and simply forgot about it as it wasn't a blocking issue (in that app). Perhaps you could report this to Apple.

Comment: @meaning-matters I found that the solution to my issue was that I was updating my text field manually (returning false from shouldChangeCharactersInRange).
It seems that populating the pasteboard is a side effect of returning true from shouldChangeCharactersInRange. Hopefully this helps someone in the future :)